# How to render a VisualElement to a Vector Based Image?

Tags: wpf, graphics, charts, wpf-controls, rendering

I am working on a Chart Control,
I need to implement the Chart Snapshot feature for capturing a vector based image in high quality of Curves and Texts, in any requested size.

Can anyone suggest me any solution or a pointer to resolve this problem.

Any kind of help in deeply appreciated.

Comment: You need to draw the vector image yourself?

Comment: Yes, I need to draw a Vector based Image, which can be re-sized in target location, without loosing the quality of drawing...!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to save your image in a vector format you can using tracing. [Potrace](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/) is an open source bitmap-to-vector tracer library (but considers that bitmap tracing is imperfect). Also considers that wpf is linked closely with [XAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Application_Markup_Language), a vector graphics markup languages, so you may want [convert raster graphics to XAML](http://weblogs.asp.net/rrobbins/archive/2007/11/11/how-to-convert-raster-graphics-to-xaml.aspx) (though Charles Petzold [you can't embed a bitmap in a XAML file](http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2006/08/230443.html))

If you need to draw a vector image you can use the [Shape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.shape.aspx) element that provides a base class for shape elements, such as Ellipse, Polygon, and Rectangle; and add the shape as [Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.aspx) child. If you are dealing with thousands of shape I suggest to use the [DrawingVisual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingvisual.aspx) class, a visual object that can be used to render vector graphics on the screen, and its RenderOpen method.

To zoom you have to work with transformations, in particular [ScaleTrasnform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.scaletransform.aspx) and apply the transformation to your panel or to your shapes.

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks gliderkite for your response, But I want to save image in some Vector Format which can be re-sizable outside the application context. Normally when we render a image we have to use RenderTargetBitmap, which is a Raster graphics but I want it to be in vector format as it renders inside wpf..

Comment: Thanks again, I will try to implement the solution this way if it can fetch some results..!!

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I want to be able to do the exact same thing but cannot find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at XamlToy but I have not already try it.
http://xamltoys.codeplex.com/