# Save a WPF UserControl as a vector image

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have created a WPF UserControl library. And I would like to put a vector picture of each UserControl (in default settings) to documentation. So my question is: How do I create a vector image of a UserControl?

Thanks for any efforts.

Comment: Suggestions here might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160740/how-to-render-a-visualelement-to-a-vector-based-image

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it doesn't seem like a bad option, however I've been rather wondering if there isn't a more elegant way to achieve this directly from XAML (and code behind). However unless someone brings a better way I'll use the Potrace program as you suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capture a **vector** image seems difficult, and is you control composed of vector graphics only? If you just wish to get a png or bmp, below code might help:

```
ImageCapturer.SaveToPng(AnyControl, "Capture.png");

class ImageCapturer
{               
    public static void SaveToBmp(FrameworkElement visual, string fileName)
    {
        var encoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
        SaveUsingEncoder(visual, fileName, encoder);
    }

    public static void SaveToPng(FrameworkElement visual, string fileName)
    {
        var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        SaveUsingEncoder(visual, fileName, encoder);
    }

    private static void SaveUsingEncoder(FrameworkElement visual, 
                 string fileName, BitmapEncoder encoder)
    {
        RenderTargetBitmap bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(
               (int)visual.ActualWidth, 
               (int)visual.ActualHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        bitmap.Render(visual);
        BitmapFrame frame = BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap);
        encoder.Frames.Add(frame);

        using (var stream = File.Create(fileName))
        {
            encoder.Save(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how to get the AnyControl name, based on xaml file?

Comment: It is an example, placeholder, it's the usercontrol you want to capture.

Comment: I'm using WPF MVVM and I want to use the name of an usercontrol but it cannot be detected by IntelliSense.. Any tips please? Or a sample project? I would be grateful!!